# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException looping?

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

This is a loop inside other loops, `s[]` is a char array. By this I am moving char step by step.what should I do for correcting it

```
for(k=j; s[k]!='\0' ;k++)    
{                         
   s[k]=s[k+1];                          
}
```

Comment: What's the size of `s[]` array?

Comment: both statements `s[k]!='\0'` and `s[k+1]` will eventually throw your exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that arrays in Java have a length, so your null terminated check is wrong. Since you access the `k+1`'th element inside the loop, `k` must not go beyond `s.length - 2`.

```
for(k=j; k < s.length - 1 ;k++)
{ 
    s[k]=s[k+1];   
}
```